# React Native xcode project "Header Search Path"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Following the steps from React Native official tutorial, the xcode project created by "react-native init MyFirstRNProject" won't compile. It complains "React/xxxxx.h" can't be found.

After further investigation of this xcode project, I figured the "React" target contains a build phase "Copy Headers" which copies all exposed headers into a weird location:
"MyFirstRNProject/node_modules/react-native/React/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React"

OK, cool, at least we got the header location. We can change the copied location to somewhere else that better than this. So whichever the project that do "#import < React/xxxxx.h >" should have above path in "Header Search Path" in build settings. Unfortunately, **all projects have "Header Search Path" empty**. And that's why I'm getting tons of header not found error.

OK, let's add it. Now it finds headers, but compilation still failed, see reference below:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21482

The discussion above saying that removing the "Header Search Path" of the projects will solve the problem. But we know that without header search path, it again can't find React headers.

Just curious now, I don't think my setup is wrong, does anyone has the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem on fresh install of Xcode **10.1**
There are few steps to follow to compile the new project after `react-native init appName`

1. In **Xcode**, Select **File** -> **Project**/**Workspace** Settings. You will see a **Build System** option to select the **Legacy Build System** as shown below

[image: Set Legacy Build System]

2. Change **Advanced** settings, and set **Build Location** to **Custom** and change paths to **Relative to Workspace** and **Build/** to **build/Build/** as showed.

[image: Build Path set up]
 3. User **Debug** for **command-line builds**(for `react-native run-ios` to work properly)

[image: Command-line builds mode]

4. **Clear** your project

After this manipulations(don't need set header search paths) you'll be able to build and run empty project via **Xcode** or **CLI**

Comment: Wow it works for me. Thanks! Sorry for the late reply. Btw are the steps above documented somewhere?